# greenlet in Win 7: DLL failed: the specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, dll, windows-7-x64, importerror

I'm running into an ImportError while trying to implement some distributed computing code using the Python [SCOOP](http://code.google.com/p/scoop/) library. One of SCOOP's dependencies is [greenlet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet), which I installed (via cygwin) using easy_install greenlet. When attempting to import this module I receive the following error:

```
>>> import greenlet
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>
```

I've tried modifying my path to include the directory containing greenlet.pyd but the module still is not imported successfully. After opening greenlet.pyd in DependencyWalker I found 10 separate .dll's that could not be found by my system. Does anyone have experience working around this issue? Downloading 10 .dll's is rather cumbersome and I'm concerned I'm not doing something correctly on the front-end.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 32 bit on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. Any help is greatly appreciated -- thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Installing Python 2.7.5 solved this problem for me.

Comment: Ran into the same symptom with greenlet 0.4.1 trying to get gevent installed on python 2.7.3.  Python 2.7.5 indeed solved this for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to 2.7.5 and it worked. Any ideas why?